# Search for specific information within a json file

Tags: python, json, api

So I am trying to locate and acquire data from an api, I am fine with actually getting the data which is in json format from the api into my python program, however I am having troubles searching through the json for the specific data I want.

Here is a basic idea of what the json file from the api looks like:

```
{
   "data": {
      "inventory": {
         "object_name": {
            "amount": 8,
         },
```

(Obviously the } close, I just didn't copy them)

I am trying to locate the amount within the json file of a specific object.

So far, here is the code I have, however, I have run into the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

I have researched the error and it appears to be caused usually by a faulty json file, however as I have imported the json file from an api, it having issues is not the case and must be an issue with some of the converting to strings and such I have done in my code.

```
data = requests.get('[api]',
    headers={
    "[api key name]" : "[api key]"
    })

dataJson = data.json()
dataStr = str(dataJson)

amt = json.loads(dataStr)['data'].get('inventory').get('object_name').get('amount')
```

As stated previously, the main issue I have is actually collecting the data I need from the json endpoint, everything is fine with getting the data into the python script.

Comment: why do you convert the JSON to a string and then back to JSON? `data.json()` is already in JSON format

Comment: @gold_cy Yeah im not too sure, but removing that solved my problem, I didnt need to convert it to a string at all really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataJson = data.json()` is already python `dict` no need to `json.loads(dataStr)` just use

```
data = requests.get('[api]',
    headers={
    "[api key name]" : "[api key]"
    })

dataJson = data.json()

amt = dataStr['data'].get('inventory').get('object_name').get('amount')
```